# Get groups with duplicated values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, group-by, duplicates

For example, if we have the following dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 1], ['a', 1],
                            ['b', 1], ['b', 2],
                            ['c', 2], ['c', 2], ['c', 2]],
                            ['col1', 'col2'])

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   a|   1|
|   a|   1|
|   b|   1|
|   b|   2|
|   c|   2|
|   c|   2|
|   c|   2|
+----+----+
```

I want to mark groups based on `col1` where values in `col2` repeat themselves. I have an idea to find the difference between the group size and the count of distinct values:

```
window = Window.partitionBy('col1')
df.withColumn('col3', F.count('col2').over(window)).\
withColumn('col4', F.approx_count_distinct('col2').over(window)).\
select('col1', 'col2', (F.col('col3') - F.col('col4')).alias('col3')).show()
```

Maybe you have a better solution. My expected output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   1|   1|
|   a|   1|   1|
|   b|   1|   0|
|   b|   2|   0|
|   c|   2|   2|
|   c|   2|   2|
|   c|   2|   2|
+----+----+----+
```

As you can see all groups where `col3` is equal to zero have only unique values in `col2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your needs, you can consider grouping statistics according to `col1` and `col2`.

```
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.expr('count(*) over (partition by col1,col2) - 1'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```